# Why is time considered as a numeric covariate than a factor in longitudinal study analysis?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, time-varying-covariate

I am running an analysis with longitudinal study design. I have previously described data my data [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317404/how-to-do-time-series-analysis-for-2x2x2-factorial-design). In general, why is time considered as a numeric variable rather than a factor in a longitudinal analysis?

Answer (score 1):

This might seem obvious, but time is a continuous variable, thereby it is a numeric variable. Factors are normally used when we have group variables, as `sex`. We can't really measure the "difference" between `male` and `female`, but we know what means a difference of one unit of time.